# change packages icon in intellij idea

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, icons, packaging

I used a plugin or theme or some thing like that in intellij idea and it make my packages even files icon in project different . Unfortunately i changed my intellij version and it gone

**entities** and **services** and **controllers** packages also shown differently.

if you used it can you help me to add this extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [plugin's search](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/search?tags=Theme&tags=User%20Interface) for `Theme` and `User Interface` tags to search for the UI Theme plugin.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
FILE >> SETTINGS >> Plugins >> install Atom Material Icons
```

Warning: this changes Ide icons too